# CSS assign class to child elements that are not a specific type

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have a `DIV` element whose id is `mydiv`.

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <div></div>
   <span></span>
   <p></p>
</div>
```

I want to assign a CSS class to only those direct descendants of this div that are not span elements. So in the above example the class should be assigned only to the child `div` and `p` elements. How do I accomplish this using CSS (not Javascript)?

Comment: You want to assign a CSS class, using CSS?

Comment: What kind of a question is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot):

```
#mydiv > *:not(span){
    color: #f00;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbymL06n/)

Note: You are not assigning a CSS class, you are applying a group of CSS styles to a particular selection.

Comment: @StevenSmith Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 3):

You can't "add a class" with CSS, but you can select elements and apply style to them if that's what you mean.

```
#mydiv > :not(span) { /* apply style to direct descendants that aren't span */ }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot